# how to use the camera class in android to view what is in front of the camera ..and not click photos

Tags: android, camera

i wnat to make an andoir app in which i want to use the camera ... only to view what is in front of the camera and not to click an image ...what is the code for it..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recomend downloading the ZXing library for bar code scanning, the code is open source and it does what you want. Start from there and modify it a bit until you get something that works. There is a new 1.6 version out, but I've been using 1.5 and it works just fine, 1.6 gave me some trouble getting it to compile.

You can download it here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Answer (score 0):

Use the android.hardware.camera class. Details here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

You don't have to write the code for storing/clicking the picture. Just use the SurfaceView. A tutorial for Augmented Reality is available here: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/42482/1954